# How to make material cards in layout act like urls?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am new to angular material. I'm using material-cards in row layout.I want those cards to act like urls. When I right click on them I want to have options like Open in a new tab and all.If you can help me then that would be great.[image]

Comment: wrapping them in <a> doesn't work?

Comment: If i try that then the layout is not working

Comment: You may use Menu or Button.

Comment: I don't want to use that.

Comment: It seems like you are fighting the Angular Material spec at that point and trying to make a component to do something it wasn't meant to do. I think your best bet would be to create a new component which wraps it's contents in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually wrapping in  tag works as @jeff-carey suggested above, I've just tried in Chrome browser:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="display:block">
    <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
             TEST
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</a>
```

But seems it's not so good from ideological prospective.